# Roles - Parse.com Javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, roles

At the moment I have javascript that allows all users from the (_User) table to log in. I have set up a Role called (Admins) within the role table and assigned one user to this role. Would this be an if statement?

At the moment this is how the user logs in successfully

```
$scope.logIn = function(form) {
Parse.User.logIn(form.username, form.password, {
  success: function(user) {
    $scope.currentUser = user;
    $scope.$apply();
    window.location.href = "TEST.html";
  },
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question "Would this be an if statement?"?  Is it, you'd like to know how the program can determine whether the logged in user belongs to the admin role?

Comment: Yes I would like only the users with an admin role to be able to log in. @danh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to check whether any user belongs to a role.  The only tricky part is to realize that the check includes a query, and is therefore an asynchronous operation.  So first, a general purpose role checking function:

```
function userHasRole(user, roleName) {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
    query.equalTo("name", roleName);
    query.equalTo("users", user);
    return query.find().then(function(roles) {
        return roles.length > 0;
    });
}
```

This returns a promise that will be fulfilled with a boolean, so you can call it like this:

```
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
// is the user an "admin"?
userHasRole(currentUser, "admin").then(function(isAdmin) {
    console.log((isAdmin)? "user is admin" : "user is not admin");
});
```

Apply it like this in your code. In the view:

```
<form role="form" name="loginForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="user.username" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" ng-model="user.password" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-ar btn-primary" ng-click="pressedLogIn()">Log in</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And in the controller:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp.controllers').controller('LogInController', LogInController);

    LogInController.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function LogInController($scope) {
        $scope.user = { username:"", password:""};

        function userHasRole(user, roleName) {
            // defined exactly as above
            // my real app has a user service, and this would be better placed there
        }

        $scope.pressedLogIn = function() {
            if ($scope.loginForm.$valid) {
                Parse.User.logIn($scope.user.username, $scope.user.password).then(function(user) {
                    $scope.user = user;
                    return userHasRole(user, "administrator");
                }).then(function(isAdmin) {
                    alert("user is admin = " + isAdmin);
                }, function(e) {
                    alert(error.message);
                });
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

Comment: hi @danh it doesn't seem to be working.. It says 'user is admin' for the 'administrator' profile but when i refresh the page it says 'user is not admin' and the same for non-admins - ('user is admin' - i refresh and it says user is not admin'. Any idea?

Comment: @NathanGreen, that is strange.  The only state change I can imagine occurring after the reload is the current user going away.  What happens if you reload a third time?

Comment: I still get random values - it says not an admin then is an admin etc.. I've attached a JSFiddle (with the Parse ID & scripts) for security reasons - could you have a review and see if you've any pointers for me. http://jsfiddle.net/NathanGreen/0jo3cnt0/

Comment: @NathanGreen, I couldn't make sense of the fiddle.  It had the login button's ng-click calling the login function with mismatching parameters, and that function seemed to get run on the currentUser before any login happened, and it wasn't clear how you were viewing the result using $scope.apply(), etc.  So I edited to include pretty much the exact login I have running in a real app.  Hopefully you'll find it useful.

Comment: that code works perfect - I have a bit of conflict between the Parse javascript file and another javascript file but alls working now - great thanks!